# JavaScript Truncate String at the Last NewLine Character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, newline, truncate

I am trying to cut a string which is smaller than a certain size and cut it at the last encountered **newline** character (`\n`).

So Far I have something like this which works and uses a space instead of a **newline**:

```
if(text.length >= maxLength){
        var a = text;

        a = a.substring(0, maxLength + 1);                  
        a = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf(" ")));

        a = a + '...';
}
```

I have tried doing `a.lastIndexOf(a.match('/\n/'))` for example but I get the wrong position. All help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `a.indexOf('\n')` to find the index of the newline character, then use `a.substring` to truncate the string.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Doesn't work

Comment: `a.indexOf('\n')` returns -1 if `\n` is not found in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lastIndexOf` function to get the last occurrence of the character `\n` as given below:

```
var i = a.lastIndexOf('\n');
```

Now check whether the character `\n` is present in the string `a` and if present then store the truncated string in the variable `a` as shown below:

```
if (i !== -1) {
    a = a.substring(0, i);
}
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, consider adding some context as to why this solution answers the question at hand.